# problems with rscala download

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to download rscala on r 3.3.2

Tha't the message that I am getting:

- installing *source* package 'rscala' ...
  ** package 'rscala' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
  Warning: running command 'sh ./configure.win' had status 127
  ERROR: configuration failed for package 'rscala'
- removing 'C:/Users/deebb/OneDrive/Documents/R/win-library/3.3/rscala'
  Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-33~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\deebb\OneDrive\Documents\R\win-library\3.3" C:\Users\deebb\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpgXcsFp/downloaded_packages/rscala_3.2.6.tar.gz' had status 1
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rscala’ had non-zero exit status

Any idea?

Comment: Why shiny tag ?

Comment: Maybe update to the latest R version (v3.5.2)?

Comment: Also you need to include full error messages from R terminal